# journalctl process groups

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, syslog, systemd-journald

I recently tried setting up the `ChrootDirectory` property in `sshd_config` and ran into the ownership problems for chroot targets.

After i have fixed the problem i noticed that `syslog-ng` had created log entries in `auth.log`:

```
Feb 21 18:56:18 raspberry sshd[28194]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/smacktard"
```

Since i am running arch linux, the main logging facility is the journal system of `systemd`. However, `journalctl -fu sshd` did not show these log entries.

So i missed these log entries. If i had seen them, i would have fixed the problem faster.
I don't want that to happen again, so i did some research:

I figured out that this happened because the `-u` option of `journalctl` filters for systemd units. However, the error is produced and logged by a child process of `sshd`. That means it has a different PID and therefore is not recognised as the systemd unit `sshd.service`.

**How can i systematically find journal entries of child processes?**

Answer (score 1):

I have two throughts.

1. Try this to see all `sshd` messages: `journalctl _COMM=sshd`
2. `sshd` is somehow configured to log to `syslog-ng`, not using the whole `systemctl`/`journalctl` thing.

The Arch Linux people say you really shouldn't need to run `syslog` or `syslog-ng` after converting to using `systemd`. Since you've got `syslog-ng` and `systemd`/`journald` on the same machine, do you have a `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.pacnew` file?  I recently upgraded, so I don't have a machine that used to not run `systemd` but now does, so I can't confirm that `sshd_config` gets updated during that transition.

Comment: `journalctl -f` (without the unit filter) shows the log messages so `sshd` and its childs log to both `syslog-ng` and `journald`. AFAIK, no application can control to which logging facility it wants to log. So if your system has both `journald` and `syslog-ng` all logs go to both. To your first point: It works! Thank you.